# Como animar sprite sheets?

Tags: javascript, spritesheet

Gostaria de uma ajuda com JavaScript. Alguém poderia fornecer-me um código básico de animação de uma única *sprite sheet*... Se possível o código HTML também.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spritesheet é uma imagem que contem dentro dela outras imagens. Muito á semelhança de uma fita de filme de antigamente que tinha fotografias que ao serem alternadas rapidamente dão o efeito de animação.

Algumas spritesheets são só uma tira (só uma linha) com N imagens, outras são mais quadradas e têm as imagens divididas por diversas "linhas".

Uma regra importante é que todas as imagens dentro da spritesheet têm de ter a mesma dimensão (altura x largura).

Dei uma olhada na internet e encontrei esta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se olharmos para ela vemos que tem 10 imagens, 5 por linha, e dimensão total de 900 x 495 pixels. Isso quer dizer que cada imagem tem 180 x 247.5 pixels.

Criei então uma `<div>` com a imagem lá dentro. Dei à div a altura da imagem e dei também `overflow: hidden;` para não revelar o resto da imagem que sai fora desse tamanho que é de uma imagem única.

Depois criei uma lógica para ir mudando de posição, tendo em conta que são 10 imagens, 2 linhas e 5 por linha.

Um exemplo fica assim:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img');

var pos = 0;
var largura = 180;
var altura = 247.5;

function prox() {
    pos++;
    if (pos == 10) pos = 0;
    var linha = Math.floor(pos / 5) * altura;
    var coluna = pos % 5 * largura;
    img.style.marginTop = -linha + 'px';
    img.style.marginLeft = -coluna + 'px';
}
setInterval(prox, 100);
```

```css
div {
    width: 180px;
    height: 247.5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://img13.deviantart.net/7fc3/i/2012/288/4/7/volt_sprite_sheet_by_kwelfury-d5hx008.png" alt="">
</div>
```

(jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szkc2n7b/1/)

Se quiseres vêr uma versão onde revela o que se está a passar melhor podes vêr aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/szkc2n7b/

Comment: Obrigado!! era exatamente o que eu procurava!